# Maskedtextbox Mask change depending to OS language

Tags: c#, winforms, maskedtextbox

Hello I have created `maskedtextbox` in my WinForms app with mask: `0/0 AAAAA` and when I do install this on PC where Czech language is set as default it converts the backslash into dot so I have `0.0 AAAAA`

May I ask if is there any way to avoid this automatic change?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `/` character in the Mask property is the *date separator*.  It is automatically localized, in Czech the `.` character is the date separator.

You'll need to *escape* the character to let it know that you meant the literal.  Use `0\/0 AAAAA` instead.  Note that added backslash.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the `Culture` property of your `MaskedTextBox` to English culture (because you don't care about the local culture):

```
yourMaskedTextBox.Culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
//or set it to an InvariantCulture
yourMaskedTextBox.Culture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change this behaviour thru the Control Panel configuration window "Region and Language" settings.